# Playing YouTube video in iPhone only app - loss of controls

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, xamarin.ios, xamarin

The code below is used to put a small WebView on a View so that the user can tap it and the video opens in full screen mode and plays. All that works, but after 4 seconds of play the controls disappear and will not reappear (tapping, rotating...). Once the video finishes, the controls reappear and the 'Done' button becomes available. However once the WebView is disposed of and a new view loaded, that new view is unresponsive for up to 6 minutes.

```
[Preserve (AllMembers=true)]
public class YouTubeViewer :  UIWebView
{
    public static AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;

    public YouTubeViewer(string url, RectangleF frame)
    {
        Log.WriteLog("loading YouTubeView");
        appDelegate.firstViewing = true;
        this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        this.Frame = frame;
        string youTubeVideoHTML = @"<object width=""{1}"" height=""{2}""><param name=""movie""
                            value=""{0}""></param><embed
                            src=""{0}"" type=""application/x-shockwave-flash"" 
                            width=""{1}"" height=""{2}""</embed></object>"; 

        string html = string.Format(youTubeVideoHTML, url, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height);
        this.LoadHtmlString(html, null);

    }
}
```

Here is how the WebView is disposed of:

```
public void RemoveWebView(UIWebView inView)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.WriteLog("RemoveWebView");
            NSUrlCache.SharedCache.RemoveAllCachedResponses();
            NSUrlCache.SharedCache.DiskCapacity = 0;
            NSUrlCache.SharedCache.MemoryCapacity = 0;

            inView.LoadHtmlString("",null);
            inView.EvaluateJavascript("var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];body.style.backgroundColor=(body.style.backgroundColor=='')?'white':'';");
            inView.EvaluateJavascript("document.open();document.close()");
            inView.StopLoading();
            inView.Delegate = null;
            inView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            inView.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.LogError("RemoveWebView",ex);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Rick, did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: Xamarin has logged this as a bug - I've yet to hear of any resolution.

Comment: Xamarin confirms that the problem is theirs and not Apples. They converted my test app into Obj-C and the problem disappeared. They then tracked the issues to the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations override. If that is removed the problem goes away. Just wish I could live without it.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to Xamarin and they suggested removing the override for orientation management in the AppDelegate.

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
    {  /*... code ...*/  }
```

After I removed this override my application worked as expected when loading YouTube videos.
This resolved the issue for me. You can still control supported orientations via individual ViewController overrides and globally via the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nishanil/YouTubePlayeriOS 
Hope this sample helps you. It worked well for me.