# Single Youtube Video Embedding in Xamarin Forms but Not Youtube list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, youtube-api

I want to integrate a Youtube Video  in a `Xamarin.forms` Application.

Currently i have googled and found the following links:

https://www.thewissen.io/embedding-youtube-feed-xamarin-forms/

[XAMARIN - add video from youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184587/xamarin-add-video-from-youtube)

but they deal with only Youtube lists , but not a single Youtube video.

I would like a single Video which isn't played in a `WebView`

How can i tackle this?

Comment: @user1 , any clue ?

Comment: I would look at [Rox.VideoPlayer nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rox.Xamarin.Video/) or [Xamarin Video Player](https://components.xamarin.com/view/video-player) they both seem to allow you to stream from youtube. Although the second link costs $50. But the first one is free

Comment: i saw the second link already , i wanted  this  for free , anyway let me look at the first one thanks

Comment: The first one doesn't support youtube , if you know how it works with youtube , help please

Comment: Did you find A good solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
HtmlWebViewSource personHtmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
personHtmlSource.SetBinding(HtmlWebViewSource.HtmlProperty, "HTMLDesc");
personHtmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>  <div style=' position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 25px;'> <iframe style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;'  src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/bVdfj7HXuXE' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </body></html>";
var browser = new WebView();
browser.Source = personHtmlSource;
Content = browser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this!!

```
<WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8azMAqsuHs0"
        WidthRequest="500"
        HeightRequest="500"
        IsVisible="true"/>
```

Remember setting width and height is necessary, otherwise it will not show!

Best Regards