# Youtube video not playing webview in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, youtube, visual-studio-2019

[image] I am new to Xamarin Forms. I am facing one problems right now. I am tying to play YouTube video in WebView, WebView showing first look of video with play button, But after click on play button start progress bar and after 2-3 seconds stop progress bar and screen blank with black color. While I am getting message  like “Video unavailable”, How can I play the video using webview, Give me a solution to resolve this issue. I have posted screenshot above

Notes: 1) example of the url which does not work https://www.youtube.com/embed/gj8FAuexQy4
2)In AndroidManifest.xml for application tag I added android:hardwareAccelerated="true" as well as I am also given permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: please follow this link: it may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280034/single-youtube-video-embedding-in-xamarin-forms-but-not-youtube-list/48274863#48274863

Comment: For embed vedio, you could refer to this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59329/playing-an-youtube-video-from-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

If you add a youtube videos inside to your app, the play store reject it.

The best solution is [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android) to open the youtube videos on to the browser or open the youtube app like this ....

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("youtube url"));
```

Comment: I don't want open youtube, I like to play only a video on a mobile app, is it possible to play youtube video using web view?